# How do I Update-Database a migration to my azure Db instead of SQLEXPRESS

Tags: entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-migrations

My web.config has a ConnectionString to an azure database, but the `Update-Database` command uses `(DataSource: .\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention)`

How do I tell Visual Studio (the Package Manager Console) to use my azure database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `DbContext` missed the default constructor:

```
public MyDbContext()
  : base("DefaultConnection")
{
}
```

Especially the `base("DefaultConnection")` reference to the connection string made it work correctly.

Comment: Mine was misspelled and I realized that after seeing this solution. Thanks.  :)